# populate select with datajson using React js

Tags: select, reactjs, html-select, populate

I'm trying to populate a select using React js, I'm using the example given on the react js docs(https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) , which uses jquery to manage the ajax calling, I'm not able to make it work, so far i have this:

here the codepen : http://codepen.io/parlop/pen/jrXOWB

```
    //json file called from source : [{"companycase_id":"CTSPROD","name":"CTS-Production"},{"companyc  ase_id":"CTSTESTING","name":"CTS-Testing"}]
//using jquery to make a ajax call
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      opts:[]      
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var source="https://api.myjson.com/bins/3dbn8";
    this.serverRequest = $.get(source, function (result) {
      var arrTen = result[''];
      for (var k = 0; k < ten.length; k++) {
            arrTen.push(<option key={opts[k]} value={ten[k].companycase_id}> {ten[k].name} </option>);
        }

    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>        
        <select id='select1'>
          {this.state.opts}
         </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

html

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

any idea how to make it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call setState to actually update your view. Here's a workable version.

```
//json file called from source : [{"companycase_id":"CTSPROD","name":"CTS-Production"},{"companyc  ase_id":"CTSTESTING","name":"CTS-Testing"}]
//using jquery to make a ajax call
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      opts:[]      
    };
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  var source="https://api.myjson.com/bins/3dbn8";
  this.serverRequest = $.get(source, function (result) {
    var arrTen = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
        arrTen.push(<option key={result[k].companycase_id} value={result[k].companycase_id}> {result[k].name} </option>);
    }
    this.setState({
      opts: arrTen
    });
  }.bind(this));
},

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
  this.serverRequest.abort();
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <div>        
      <select id='select1'>
        {this.state.opts}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```